# ng test - By.css doesn't return expected elements

Tags: angular

```
<ng-dropdown-panel class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom" id="my-id"
    ng-reflect- klass="ng-dropdown-panel" 
    ng-reflect-items="[object Object],[object Object]"
    ng-reflect-position="auto" ng-reflect-buffer-amount="4" 
    ng-reflect-virtual- scroll="false" id="1234" style="opacity: 1;">

    <div class="ng-dropdown-panel-items scroll-host">
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="5678">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Test1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="9111">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Test2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="2311">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Test3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-dropdown-panel>
```

I have ng-dropdown-panel with-in angular form which I want to test with ng-test.

```
const options = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#my-id ng-option'));
```

but this returns undefined instead of returning options Test1, Test2, Test3. How to get those elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// to get all
const options = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('ng-dropdown-panel#my-id div.ng-dropdown-panel div.ng-option span.ng-option-label'));

// to get the first one
const option = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ng-dropdown-panel#my-id div.ng-dropdown-panel div.ng-option span.ng-option-label'));
```

Comment: my-id is there on the first line. I need to use id specific to this ng-dropdown because I have multiple drondown. How can I combine it with id?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't see it at first. I have edited my answer to include `#my-id`.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(fixture.nativeElement)` to see your HTML that the test is seeing and see if the elements are there in the string.

Comment: You were right, the dropdown element was not visible until ng.select was clicked. This link explained how to solve it https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/919.